# Existence of well-order on an arbitrary infinite set $X$ such that $X$ has a largest element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

One can prove that every set $X$ can be well-ordered. Can we also prove (or disprove) that for any arbitrary infinite set $X$ there exists a well-order such that there is a largest element, that is, there exists $x \in X$ such that $\forall y \in X: y \leq x$?

Comment: Make the smallest element the biggest!

Comment: @Unit Will the whole set continue to have a minimum?

Comment: @Will If $X$ has a least element $x$, then $X \setminus \{x\}$ has a least element, too.

Comment: OK. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

Say $a\in X$. Well-order $X\setminus\{a\}$,  then add $a$ at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Choose an ordinal $\alpha$ of cardinality $|X|$. Since $X$ is infinite, $|X|+1=|X|$, so $|\alpha+1|=|X|$.

Then choose any bijection between $\alpha+1$ and $X$. This gives a well ordering on $X$ with a largest element. (That corresponding to the element $\alpha$ of $\alpha+1$.)

Comment: @anonymous_downvoter, if you have suggestions for how I could improve this answer, do let me know.